# For loop using pointers to traverse array not working properly

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, pointers

For my homework problem I must use pointers to traverse arrays. When I try to store 3 "name" values into member variables of an array of an `Object` called `RentalAgency`, I find that it stores the value, but never increments. Therefore the last value given is stored in the first index and the next two are empty.

```
RentalAgency *agencies_ptr = agencies;

for(int i = 0; i < 3;i++,++agencies_ptr){
    infile.get((agencies->name),MAX_SIZE,space);
}
```

Where `agencies` is an array of Objects

If the input is Hertz, Alamo, and Budget, it should output Hertz, Alamo, and Budget.
The actual output is just Budget.

Comment: Typo perhaps? You need `infile.get((agencies_ptr->name), MAX_SIZE, space);`

Comment: what is `agencies` ? How can we know whether `++agencies_ptr` makes sense without seeing `agencies` ?

Comment: Ah yes you are correct, I am new to pointers and do not understand. Thank you @RSahu

Answer (score 0):

Just write

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    infile.get( agencies_ptr[i].name, MAX_SIZE, space );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are desreferencing `agencies`, not `agencies_ptr` (and the parenthesis are not needed):

```
RentalAgency *agencies_ptr = agencies;

for(int i = 0; i < 3; ++i, ++agencies_ptr)
   infile.get(agencies_ptr->name, MAX_SIZE, space);
```

But a more idiomatic way of traversing a "range" is this (`it` stands for `iterator`):

```
RentalAgency *agencies_it = agencies;
RentalAgency *agencies_end = agencies_it + 3;

for(; agencies_it != agencies_end; ++agencies_it)
   infile.get(agencies_it->name, MAX_SIZE, space);
```

It's cleaner, express intent better and is more familiar to see among experienced programmers.